# how i group all row data by months and not eliminate with some date using group by

Tags: mysql

i`m having a hard time trying to group all row data by dates.
this is my table

```
id     date       Company
---|----------|-------------
 1 |2017-06-25|   Inzpect
 2 |2017-07-04|   Inzpect  
 3 |2017-06-25|   Meralco
 4 |2017-06-27|   Ginebra
 5 |2017-06-26|   Inzpect
```

and this is my sql

```
SELECT date ,company FROM tbl_reports WHERE YEAR(date) = '2017' group by date
```

this is the result i get to my sql

```
    date       Company
------------|----------
 2017-06-25 |  Inzpect
 2017-06-26 |  Inzpect  
 2017-06-27 |  Ginebra
 2017-07-04 |  Inzpect
```

why it does not get all the data from my table and eliminate 1 of my row

the thing i want to get is i want to get all rows and group it by dates but it always elimante some row with the same date :/ .

```
   date       Company
------------|----------
 2017-06-25 |  Inzpect
 2017-06-25 |  Meralco
 2017-06-26 |  Inzpect  
 2017-06-27 |  Ginebra
 2017-07-04 |  Inzpect
```

can you help me guys :(

Comment: Group by is an aggregation function I suspect you want an order by.

Comment: I'm guessing you use `mysql`, not `sql server` since this would give you an error in sql server (as it should, cause it can't be inferred what you intent to do). Please don't tag products not in use! What did you expect to happen? You are grouping, so naturally rows are grouped together. That's exactly what `group by` is intended to do. Also, why are you grouping but not aggregating?

Comment: _“why it does not get all the data from my table and eliminate 1 of my row”_ – well _because_ you grouped by date. You have two records with the same date, so of course grouping by date “condenses” those two to one single record. That is what GROUP BY _does_. If you do not want that, then why are you using it in the first place? And btw., selecting columns that are not part of the grouping is illegal in SQL; MySQL _tolerates_ this error if configured to do so, but the results will be “random”.

Comment: ow sory order by is the right syntax.. sory i dont read to much sql dont notice there is order by ..  thanks for all your comment i`m new in sql and exploring new learning ..

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
SELECT `date`, company
FROM tbl_reports
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = '2017'
order by `date`;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `year()` is a function that returns a number, so don't put single quotes around the comparison.  This is better:

```
where year(date) = 2017
```

Second, it is better (for performance) to do date comparisons directly and not use functions.

Others have mentioned that you seem to want `order by`.  This is a good version of the query:

```
select r.date, r.company 
from tbl_reports r
where r.date >= '2017-01-01' and r.date < '2018-01-01'
order by r.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need an `ORDER BY` Not an aggregated function like `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT date ,company FROM tbl_reports WHERE YEAR(date) = '2017' ORDER BY date
```

`GROUP BY` The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

`ORDER BY` The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in descending order, use the DESC keyword.